# what is the encoding of this string,'base64' or 'utf-8'??? ,how can i get it readable

Tags: javascript, python

```
print "4-12\u4e2a\u82f1\u6587\u5b57\u6bcd\u3001\u6570\u5b57\u548c\u4e0b\u5212\u7ebf".decode('base64')#no
```

thanks

---

and

if i have '4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'

how can i get the string '4-12\u4e2a\u82f1\u6587\u5b57\u6bcd\u3001\u6570\u5b57\u548c\u4e0b\u5212\u7ebf'

is

```
print '4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.decode('what')#
```

i write:

```
print u'4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.encode('unicode-escape')
```

it print

```
4-12\xb8\xf6\xd3\xa2\xce\xc4\xd7\xd6\xc4\xb8\xa1\xa2\xca\xfd\xd7\xd6\xba\xcd\xcf\xc2\xbb\xae\xcf\xdf
```

not the string "`4-12\u4e2a\u82f1\u6587\u5b57\u6bcd\u3001\u6570\u5b57\u548c\u4e0b\u5212\u7ebf`

```
print u'4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode-escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "encodings\utf_8.pyo", line 16, in decode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

no 'u' is also error:

```
print '4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode-escape')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "encodings\utf_8.pyo", line 16, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 4: unexpected code byte
```

---

it's ok,thanks

```
>>> print '4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.decode('gb2312').encode('unicode-escape')
4-12\u4e2a\u82f1\u6587\u5b57\u6bcd\u3001\u6570\u5b57\u548c\u4e0b\u5212\u7ebf
```

Comment: I don't know what it is, but it is NOT base64.

Comment: \u = unicode code points maybe?

Comment: Trying a new way of posting it so it does not get closed this time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083389/how-do-i-break-this-script-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final comment:

```
>>> print '4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.decode('gb2312').encode('unicode-escape')
```

would only work if your source file is saved in gb2312 encoding.  Make sure you declare that at the top of your file, then you can use Unicode strings:

```
# coding: gb2312
print u'4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线'.encode('unicode-escape')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a Unicode representation. Try `.decode('unicode-escape')`.

**EDIT:**

For the second decode, what you use depends on your terminal/console settings. `'utf-8'` is a sane starting point, then encode using `'unicode-escape'`  in order to get the Unicode escape sequences.

Comment: Aaaand... what *is* it printing?

Comment: it print '4-12\xb8\xf6\xd3\xa2\xce\xc4\xd7\xd6\xc4\xb8\xa1\xa2\xca\xfd\xd7\xd6\xba\xcd\xcf\xc2\xbb\xae\xcf\xdf'

Comment: You *did* read the part that says that you need to decode with `'utf-8'` first, right?

Comment: Do note that your original did *not* have the `u` prefix.

Comment: Ah, I see why. your terminal is `'gb2312'`, not 'utf-8'.

Answer (score 1):

It's encoded as a python unicode literal:

```
>>> print u"4-12\u4e2a\u82f1\u6587\u5b57\u6bcd\u3001\u6570\u5b57\u548c\u4e0b\u5212\u7ebf"
4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线
```

Comment: Close, but no. It is in fact a str literal, containing a unicode repr.

Comment: @Ignacio: Well, as it's written it's a str literal that gets decoded as base64. Clearly that's not correct, who knows if it really is supposed to be a str literal. Maybe just adding a `u` to make it a unicode literal is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That string says "4-12个英文字母、数字和下划线", by just typing it in to a JavaScript interpreter (in this case, the WebKit inspector).

It does not appear to have any base64 encoded information in it.

Was there something else that you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is python 3.x representation of unicode string.

In python 2.x you will need `u""` at the start of unicode string.